# Rewrite rule to drop .html and to keep the querystring while navigating between pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I have html pages and I want to remove the .html and keep the query-string in place that when a visitor comes in with a query-string and navigate between pages the query-string remains in place.

So far getting the .html to go is fine, but I cannot get the query-string to stay between pages. I don't particularly want to introduce php into my pages, if its possible with a rewrite rule that will be great.

As follows: 
Visitor comes in on homepage www.example.com?ID=123 
When visitor clicks on the link www.example.com/page1.html , I want the visitor to go to www.example.com/page1?ID=123

My code currently is as follows:

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

Thanks

Comment: This is not possible. You could use some javascript to store this ID inside a cookie, so it is persistent across different requests.